# SQL* Is there a way to make a procedure that will verify what time and day?(Beginner) SQL*

Tags: sql, plsql

It's for a school project and I know it may seems basic but I'm wondering how to make a procedure that will verify what time and day it's actually is like monday and not the date. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this -

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'Day') from dual;
```

Pls note, you can use 'DAY' to get all caps, 'Day' to get initcaps. There are whole lot of things you can do in terms of formatting the date. You can refer to the link below.
https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_GCEY1DN2CN5HZCUQFHVUYQD3G.html

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `'Dy'` and using 3-character abbreviations for the date:

```
select to_char(sysddate, 'Dy')
```

The reason is that if you use `'Day'` it pads the name with spaces.  So, you end up with seeming absurdities such as this:

```
select (case when to_char(date '2000-01-01', 'Day') = 'Saturday' then 1 else 0 end),
      to_char(date '2000-01-01', 'Day') 
from dual;
```

I should also note that `to_char()` takes a third parameter for the language so you don't have to use English names.